# get WifiP2pDevice information from WifiP2pDeviceList

Tags: android, p2p, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I am developing an android application which sends data between two android devices using wifi-direct.So far i was able to get the detected device inside onPeersAvailable method . (the code given below)

```
@Override
public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {

                        peersdevices.clear();
                        peersdevices.addAll(peers.getDeviceList());

}
```

Now i want to display the devices name in a list view. I don't know how to access each `WifiP2pDevice` information from `WifiP2pDeviceList`.

When i used the following code from official documentation (given below), i get an error "cannot convert from Object to WifiP2pDevice" .

```
WifiP2pDevice device = peers.get(0);
```

I will be thankful if anyone provides the code snippet to get WifiP2pDevice information from WifiP2pDeviceList.

Thanks

Comment: refer [WifiDirectDemo](http://www.androidside.com/docs/resources/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/index.html)

Comment: Sorry ! could not find the appropriate code ....

Comment: U seen all classes? DeviceListFragments.java

Comment: yes , i got the code (which is in the question) from the DeviceListFragments.java , but could not find the code to get WifiP2pDevice information from WifiP2pDeviceList

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this.

```
for(i=0;i<WifiP2pDeviceList.size();i++){
    WifiP2pDevice device = WifiP2pDeviceList.get(i);
    String deviceName=device.deviceName;
    String devicestatus=device.status;
    //so on
    }
```

hope it helps

Comment: @TopCat  hi..is it possible to get battery status or imei no of another device using WifiP2pDevice ?

Answer (score 2):

```
                    @Override
                    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {

                        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE

                     for (  WifiP2pDevice peer : peers.getDeviceList()) {
                        WifiP2pDevice device=peer;
                        //here get the device info
                        String deviceaddr= device.deviceAddress;

                        if(device.deviceAddress.equals("somedevice")){
                            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Server  Name "+device.deviceName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
                            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
                         }

                     }
                    }
```